# Can't Push Results to JavaScript Dictionary

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, push

I am using [google trends API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-trends-api) to eventually export trends data to an excel file. The issue is I want to extract ONLY the formattedTime and value for my keywords. While Ive tried to do this, I've also noticed that `results` are not being pulled properly. For instance, when I try to push results from the API to an empty dictionary, I continue to get an empty array.

Any idea?

Thank you.

```
'use strict';

const googleTrends = require('google-trends-api');

var something = [];    

    googleTrends.interestOverTime({
        keyword: 'animals',
        startTime: new Date(Date.now() - (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000)),
        granularTimeResolution: true,
    }, function(err, results) {
        something.push(results);
        if (err)
            console.log('oh no error!', err);
        else
            console.log("--------------------------")

    });

console.log(something);
```

Example of Data Pulled:

```
{
  "default": {
     "timelineData":[
       {
         "time":"1511629200",
         "formattedTime":"Nov 25, 2017 at 12:00 PM",
         "formattedAxisTime":"Nov 25 at 12:00 PM",
         "value":[44],
         "formattedValue":["44"]
       },
       {
         "time":"1511632800",
         "formattedTime":"Nov 25, 2017 at 1:00 PM",
         "formattedAxisTime":"Nov 25 at 1:00 PM",
         "value":[41],
         "formattedValue":["41"]
       }
     }]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your call to Google is asynchronous, so you need to log out your results inside the callback where you push the results into `something`. Otherwise your `console.log(something)` is actually running *before* your callback completes, and no values have yet been pushed into your array.

```
'use strict';

const googleTrends = require('google-trends-api');

var something = [];    

googleTrends.interestOverTime({
    keyword: 'bitcoin',
    startTime: new Date(Date.now() - (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000)),
    granularTimeResolution: true,
}, function(err, results) {
    something.push(results);
    if (err)
        console.log('oh no error!', err);
    else{
        console.log(something);
        console.log("--------------------------")
    }
});
```